# Performance issue in Android MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I'm developing **Custom Map** Application in which I can get data from webservices and display overlay item base on that data. Here is the problem when I run my app it will display map and overlay correctly, but when I try to zoom it or try to tap it, it is getting slow, very slow performance. So there are some performance issues are raise over here. Infact it not contain long numbers of data only 50 overlays are there.

I have doubt that something is wrong with add item overlay, please check it and help me.

**Code:**

```
private void showWhaleDophinSightingsToMap() {
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    // Show overlay for whale sightings
    Log.i(TAG, "whaleWatchingInfoList >>>>>> " + whaleWatchingInfoList);
    Log.i(TAG, "whaleWatchingInfoList >>>>>> "+ whaleWatchingInfoList.size());
    if(whaleWatchingInfoList != null && whaleWatchingInfoList.size() > 0) {
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.north);            
            customItemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);
            for(int i = 0; i < whaleWatchingInfoList.size(); i++) {
                    if(i == 0) {
                            MapController mc = mapView.getController();
                            mc.setZoom(7);
                            // Zoom Level 
                            mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getLatitude() * 1E6),
                            (int)(whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getLongtitude() * 1E6)));
                    }else {
                            geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getLatitude() * 1E6),
                            (int)(whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getLongtitude() * 1E6));
                            CustomOverlayItem customOverlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(geoPoint, whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getName(), whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getDescription(), whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getImageUrl(), whaleWatchingInfoList.get(i).getAtdwProductUrl());
                            customItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(customOverlayItem);    
                            mapOverlays.add(customItemizedOverlay);
                    }
            }
    }
    mapView.postInvalidate();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure can answer. In my case I added 2 lines when get map view and it improve a lot of performance when map moving or zoom. And it solve my problem.

```
mapView.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
mapView.setPersistentDrawingCache(MapView.PERSISTENT_ALL_CACHES);
```

Hope it help.